# Multinomial coefficient divisible by factorial of number of terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in \Bbb N_{>0}$ and let $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of positive integers.

Then, must $\displaystyle \frac {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)!} {n! \prod_{i=1}^n a_i!}$ be an integer?

---

I know that without $n!$ it is just the multinomial coefficient, so it must be an integer. I also know that if all the $a_i$'s are equal then it is an integer since there is an obvious combinatorial interpretation.

However, I have no idea if the $a_i$'s are not all equal.

Comment: It's false, @MatheinBoulomenos propose : a_1=2, a_2=4, then 6!/(2!*2!*4!)=7.5 here : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether any "$n$-nomial" coefficient is divisible by $n!$.
What about binomial coefficients?
How about $n=2$, $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$?

Comment: @KennyLau, has forgot to precise $a_i>1$, else it's false.